# hibernate type yes_no with 'J' instead of 'Y'

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have to map a character(1) field in the database to a gorm attribute.
The field in the database is clearly a "yes_no" type, but with the exception, that the 'Y' should have the german expression 'J'.

Is there a way to handle it, or should I use a char field instead of a boolean in my gorm-class?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue with a Custom-User-Type which uses a boolean type in the grails/gorm domain class and the 'J'/'N' representation on the database side.

Prepared a github rep under:

[grails-gorm-ja_nein_type](https://github.com/susannej/grails-gorm-ja_nein_type)

Answer (score 1):

As discussed here:

- [14.10. Expressions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions)

We can use configuration setting:

> Booleans can be easily used in expressions by declaring HQL query substitutions in Hibernate configuration:
>
> `<property name="hibernate.query.substitutions">true 1, false 0</property>`
>
> This will replace the keywords true and false with the literals 1 and 0 in the translated SQL from this HQL:
>
> `from Cat cat where cat.alive = true`

As far as I know one of these options should be:

```
<property name="query.substitutions">true 1, false 0, yes 'Y', no 'N'</property>
```

so you should try:

```
<property name="query.substitutions">true 1, false 0, yes 'J', no 'N'</property>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Currently I have the problem to define this setting in grails/gorm... Because I couldn't find this property-file. I think it should be defined via the groovy-syntax... but don't know where...

Comment: Sorry I do not know grails, maybe ask different question...good luck with hibernate

Comment: I solved this issue now with a Hibernate Custom-User-Type which uses a boolean type on the code side and the 'J' and 'N' on the database side.